# Kali Linux black screen during boot

Tags: boot, bios, kali-linux

I'm trying to  install Kali Linux on an old hardware, IBM server system X3200.  The installation was successful with separate partitions for root, swap and home. It goes to the point where grub shows the boot options and tries to load the Kali kernel. It's giving me the following errors during boot.

The error is:

```
ACPI:SPCR Unexpected SPCR Access width. Defaulting to byte size.
```

[image: black screen]

The installation went fine, and I have made the entire disk into a logical partition.
I tried installing both 32-bit and 64-bit versions.

Comment: If you can't successfully install Kali by yourself, chances are great that Kali isn't the right flavor of Linux for you. Perhaps try Ubuntu or Debian.

Comment: Your key problems are not `ACPI:SPCR Unexpected SPCR Access width. Defaulting to byte size.` they are the `Gave up waiting for root file system device` and `ALERT! /dev/sdb1 does not exist.` which means that either your `/ect/fstab` is setup wrong or you installed it somewhere that the system cannot access. Without details from you showing us the contents of all important files you setup to install it or what process you used (you need to walk us through what happens at each stage, not just "I followed some guide") there is little we can do to help you.

Comment: @Eric F, The installation was successful, no errors were reported during installation.

Comment: @Mokubai I have installed using graphical interface of Kali and created seperate partitions for each directories. The shell allows you to navigate the file system and I can see the dev, etc, root, home and other folders in there.

Comment: @ken It's [early userspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_startup_process#Early_user_space), not the on-disk filesystem. As Mokubai said, it's trying to mount a nonexistent disk device. My guess is you were installing from USB drive which was named `/dev/sda` and your local disk became `/dev/sdb`, now the USB drive is missing and local disk is `/dev/sda` but fstab features `/dev/sdb`. Update fstab to use filesystem UUIDs or labels (`/dev/disk/by-partlabel/*`)

Answer (score 0):

Considering the displayed message, you should look for a BIOS update, if available.

At next, you should verify if the partition /dev/sdb1 really exist and you should verify the filesystem on it. Try to use a diagnostic system like SystemRescueCD. The just opened GRUB shell give you the opportunity to ask about available partitions on disk.

According to the display, you have at least two disk drives: /dev/sdb and /dev/sda. In the BIOS settings, verify the boot device order and verify that the partition from which one you want to boot is marked as bootable in the MBR. I recommend to use fdisk while running with a diagnostic system.